# Original class name can be found after running proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I am new in proguard and I use http://www.javadecompilers.com to verify my progurd setting.

The class name have been obfuscated. But the original class name can be found in javadecompiler.

Is there any setting to hide the original class name?

[java decompiler output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFuGj.png)

File : proguard-project.txt

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
#-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

#-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity

-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.util.Log

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
 native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*,SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# goolge map
-keep class android.location.** { *; }

-keepnames class com.google.android.maps.** {*;}
-keep public class com.google.android.maps.** {*;}

-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.MapView
-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.MapController 
-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.Overlay
-dontwarn com.google.**

-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you can determine the original file name is due to the `SourceFile` attribute in this line:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*,SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

You can change that behavior by removing it:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*,LineNumberTable
```

or by forcing ProGuard to use a placeholder instead of the original file name:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*,SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```